# Reconstructing input image from layers of a CNN

Tags: neural-network, cnn, convolution, pytorch, neural-style-transfer

I've been trying to implement neural style transfer as described in this [paper here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1508.06576.pdf) According to the paper,

> we can visualise the information at different processing stages in the
>   CNN by reconstructing the input image from only knowing the network’s
>   responses in a particular layer.

My question is, how exactly does one go about reconstructing image from a single layer?
I'm implementing this in pytorch. I've the output from layer `conv4_2` stored in a tensor of shape `[1,512,50,50]` but how do I visualize this?

Here's a part of my code, if that helps.

```
vgg = models.vgg19(pretrained=True).features

for param in vgg.parameters():
    param.requires_grad_(False)

device = torch.device("cpu")

vgg.to(device)

content_img = Image.open("image3.jpg").convert('RGB')
style_img   = Image.open("image5.jpg").convert('RGB')
content_img = transformation(content_img).to(device)
style_img   = transformation(style_img).to(device)

def get_features(image, model):

    layers = {'0': 'conv1_1', '5': 'conv2_1',  '10': 'conv3_1', 
              '19': 'conv4_1', '21': 'conv4_2', '28': 'conv5_1'}
    x = image
    features = {}

    for name, layer in model._modules.items():
        x = layer(x)

        if name in layers:
            features[layers[name]] = x   

    return features

content_img_features = get_features(content_img, vgg)
style_img_features   = get_features(style_img, vgg)

target_content = content_img_features['conv4_2']
```

How do I reconstruct the image from the output of `conv4_2`?